# For planes, do we need an up-to-date fleet count in the tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing, review

I just rejected two edit suggestions:

1. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48671

> reject reason: linked wiki articles are enough for this type of always-changing information

2. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48672

> reject reason: no need to keep the fleet numbers up-to-date here, especially when you consider the rest of the families and the lack of sub-family tags

As or writing this, the reviews aren't completed; I think it's worth discussing for future reviews.

The edits revise the number of planes in service, and given how this information changes week-by-week and year-by-year, and for *every* tag, I don't think it's worth the effort, when the same info is readily available in the linked Wikipedia articles, and how obscure it is getting to the tag wikis.

Any guidelines to fall on? Opinions?

Note: I always thought the best usage of tag wikis is a collection of answered questions, especially the most linked (frequent) ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't think we need an up-to-date fleet count in the tag wikis.

Tag wikis are [intended to describe the *usage* of a tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), not to be an encyclopedic description of the concept. Active fleet counts don't contribute to actual instructions on how to *use* the tag.

As such, I'd reject those edits and remove the fleet count.

Comment: You linked to the excerpt usage, the tag wiki link is [this one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/01/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms), and it says what you said (and I thought of), basically: *"Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain frequently asked questions about the tag and guidelines on its usage."*

Comment: @ymb1 Nope, that was the link I intended to link to. There is a tag wiki rejection reason that links to that page.

Comment: Interesting! It sounds like we should re-write every single aircraft specific tag wiki since all of them are currently encyclopedic descriptions of the aircraft...