# Reputation points from accepted tagwiki edits not attributed

Tags: bug, editing, reputation, tag-info

Yesterday (local time), I made three tagwiki edits which were ultimately accepted:<sup>1</sup>

- [Suggested edit #48672](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48672) to [airbus-a320](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a320).
- [Suggested edit #48673](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48673) to [airbus-a330](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a330).
- [Suggested edit #48677](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48677) to [airbus-beluga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-beluga).

[image: the three accepted tagwiki edits in question]

Making an edit suggestion which is then reviewed and accepted is worth +2 reputation; thus, I should have gained a total of +6 reputation from those three accepted tagwiki edits.

However, I only gained reputation for *one* of the three (suggested edit #48673):

[image: the lack-of-tagwiki-edit-acceptance-reputation-gain in question]

Why is accepted-edit reputation gain broken, and when will it get fixed?

---

<sup>1</sup>: I also made three which were rejected, but those do not concern us here.

Answer (score 6):

You got 1,000 from edit suggestions (2 points per), that's [the limit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

> Sean had 502 edit suggestions approved, and 25 edit suggestions rejected

Comment: Why does reputation from edits have a cap?  No other source of reputation does.

Comment: @Sean no clue but I remembered reading it somewhere, and there it was in the help center, I'll see if they discussed it on MSE and will add a link if I find anything

Answer (score 3):

The best source of info here is probably this Q/A

[How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

And a quote for a direct answer

> ### Can I earn reputation?
>
> - When a suggested edit is approved, the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and **the total cap for reputation gained via suggested edits is 1,000**. The +2 is reversed if the edited post is ever deleted or if the final user to review one of your suggestions gets their account deleted.
> - When a suggested edit is rejected, no reputation penalty is given, though it can count towards an editing ban.
> - **Once you have earned the edit privilege, your edits are no longer peer reviewed and no reputation is given for edits to posts**. Similarly, once you earn the trusted user privilege, your edits to tag wikis are no longer reviewed and no reputation is given for them.

Emphasis mine, highlighting the 2 ways you no longer earn rep from suggested edits.

PS: You might want to [check your edits are appropriate](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4015/for-planes-do-we-need-an-up-to-date-fleet-count-in-the-tag-wikis)